# Code duplication when converting DTO to String messages

Tags: java

In a payment application a day before and at the same time with some payments some messages(email) needs to be sent.
I have a DTO (called `EscrowPayment`, projected from some entity) from which I generate and send two similar `messages.

I look for advice specifically on the following issues with the code I ended up:

- Copy-pasted code.
- Type suffix in identifiers. eg: `nominalAmountStr`
- Static utility methods `formatInteger` etc (Used application wide).
- String constants in code. But because they are parameterized by position and not by name; if I extract them to a configuration file as they are, 
  I wouldn't know in which order I should be giving parameters to `String.format`.

Here is the code; it is sanitized and translated, but issues are clearly identifiable:

```
public class EscrowPaymentMessageServiceImpl {

    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    // .....

    @Override
    public void escrowPaymentWillBeDone(EscrowPayment escrowPayment) throws BusinessLayerException {
        try {
            String nominalAmountStr = formatInteger(new BigDecimal(escrowPayment.getNominal()));
            String paymentDateStr = dateFormat(escrowPayment.getPaymentDate(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
            String interestRateStr = format(escrowPayment.getInterestRate(), "0.00###");
            String paymentAmountStr = format(escrowPayment.getPaymentAmount());
            String messageText = String
                    .format("BLAH BLAH some security with ID %s of nominal value EUR %s "
                            + "at date %s BLAH your account with number 1234567890 will be debited to pay "
                            + "EUR %s coupon payment for %%%s interest.", 
                            escrowPayment.getSecurityId(), nominalStr, paymentDateStr, 
                            interestRateStr, paymentAmountStr);

            sendMessage(messageText);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            getLog().error("An error occured while sending the email:", e);
            throw new BusinessLayerException("EscrowPaymentMessage.MessageCouldNotBeSent", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void escrowPaymentIsDone(EscrowPayment escrowPayment) throws BusinessLayerException {
        try {
            String nominalAmountStr = formatInteger(new BigDecimal(escrowPayment.getNominal()));
            String paymentDateStr = dateFormat(escrowPayment.getPaymentDate(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
            String paymentAmountStr = format(escrowPayment.getPaymentAmount());
            String messageText = String.format("BLAH BLAH at date %s the security with ID %s of nominal value EUR %s "
                            + "BLAH your account with number 1234567890 has been debited to pay EUR %s." ,
                            paymentDateStr, escrowPayment.getSecurityId(), nominalStr, paymentAmountStr);

            sendMessage(messageText);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            getLog().error("An error occured while sending the email:", e);
            throw new BusinessLayerException("EscrowPaymentMessage.MessageCouldNotBeSent", e);
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(messageText) throws MessagingException {
        //....
    }

}
```

Comment: There's not much I can see, is using a template system like [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) an option?

Comment: Thanks @Bobby. I checking it out, but introducing a new dependency would be a little too costly for me *in this occasion*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strikes me as an occasion where a custom method with positional format indexing may help [(Formatter `argument_index`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). It is a little-known feature of Java's String.format / Formatter class, that you can reference values by their position. Consider the following methods:

```
@Override
public static final String formatEscrowPayment(String format, EscrowPayment escrowPayment) {
        String nominalAmountStr = formatInteger(new BigDecimal(escrowPayment.getNominal()));
        String paymentDateStr = dateFormat(escrowPayment.getPaymentDate(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
        String interestRateStr = format(escrowPayment.getInterestRate(), "0.00###");
        String paymentAmountStr = format(escrowPayment.getPaymentAmount());
        return String.format(format, 
                        escrowPayment.getSecurityId(), // 1
                        nominalStr,                    // 2
                        paymentDateStr,                // 3
                        interestRateStr,               // 4
                        paymentAmountStr);             // 5

}

private static final void sendExcrowMessage(String template, ExcrowPayment escrow) throws BusinessLayerException {
    try {
        String messageText = formatEscrowPayment(template, escrow);
        sendMessage(messageText);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        getLog().error("An error occured while sending the email:", e);
        throw new BusinessLayerException("EscrowPaymentMessage.MessageCouldNotBeSent", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void escrowPaymentWillBeDone(EscrowPayment escrowPayment) throws BusinessLayerException {
    sendEscrowMessage("BLAH BLAH some security with ID %1$s of nominal value EUR %2$s "
                    + "at date %3$s BLAH your account with number 1234567890 will be debited to pay "
                    + "EUR %5$s coupon payment for %%%4$s interest.",
                      escrowPayment);

@Override
public void escrowPaymentIsDone(EscrowPayment escrowPayment) throws BusinessLayerException {
        sendEscrowMessage("BLAH BLAH at date %3$s the security with ID %1$s of nominal value EUR %2$s "
                        + "BLAH your account with number 1234567890 has been debited to pay EUR %2$s." ,
}
```

Note how the substitution values are handled by their positions.... the `%1$s` references the first format value as a string. The `%3$s` references the 3rd value. You can change the order of the positional fields without having to change the positions of the values in the actual format call. Have a [look at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is what was I trying to do in the first place. But I forgot about argument indexes in format strings, and forgot that I forgot. But this is what SE is for. I'll wait for another day or two before accepting, in case someone comes up with another answer that *I don't know that I don't know* :).